# Activity has been destroyed error while showing a "loading" dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

In my test project, I want to show a loading dialog fragment to users while the application get some data from a server. The problem is that on rare occasions I got this error:

```
Activity has been destroyed  -  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1456)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:708)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:676)
at android.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:299)
at android.app.DialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss(DialogFragment.java:277)
at com.example.barta1.site_patrol.TourActivity1$20.onResponse(TourActivity1.java:897)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6166)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Here is the dialogfragment code I am using:

```
public class LoadingDialog extends DialogFragment {


Activity activity = null;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = (Activity) context;
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progressbarlayout, null);
  
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String text = bundle.getString("info");

    Button btnprogressbarlayoutCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.btnprogressbarlayoutCancel);
 

    if(text != null){
        TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.tvLoadingBar);
        tv.setText(text);
    }


    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom))
            .setView(view)
            .create();


    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

        }
    });
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


    // set the DialogFragment to make the dialog unable to dismiss with back button
    // (because not working if called on the dialog directly)
    setCancelable(false);
    return dialog;
}



@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag){
    try{
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(this, tag);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){

    }
}
```

}

And here is where it is used:

```
 RetroClientAPI retroClientAPI = ServiceGenerator.createService(RetroClientAPI.class);

    Call<List<TerDisordersModelsToOffline>> call = retroClientAPI.getTerDisordersFromRoute(tourschedid);

    dialog = new LoadingDialog();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "LoadingDialog");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("info", "Please wait...");
    dialog.setArguments(bundle);

    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<List<TerDisordersModelsToOffline>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<TerDisordersModelsToOffline>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<TerDisordersModelsToOffline>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                // HERE I GOT THE ISSUE
                dialog.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
                terdisorderslist = response.body();
                //saving database part...
               

            }
            else {
                dialog.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server error occured. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<TerDisordersModelsToOffline>> call, Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network related error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

As you may see, I am using retrofit to network calls, and this fragment should be visible until host replies. Problem is with the line: dialog.dismissAllowingStateLoss().

Seems like sometimes the activity destroyed before the fragment dismissed.

So my question is: how to avoid this crash?

Comment: would it not help to use application context instead of activity context ?

Comment: This could be the solution, but I need the source activity instance (code not presented here), because later on I want to implement some user interaction to cancel the this asynchronous network call by pressing a button on the dialogfragments layout. (in retrofit, getCall() on the (Object)activity identifies the retrofit network call (in our case see the line call.enqueue(..)) ,    and call.cancel() can interrupt, and cancel immediately an ongoing call, that is why I want to pass the activity instance to the fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete this code:

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = (Activity) context;
}
```

Why do you need this? You already have link to parent activity inside DialogFragment

Comment: Sure, I missed that I can now remove it. I will delete this code and post the results. (Testing will take some time, because the issue originally occurs occasionally)

Comment: And as advice, try avoid type coercion. This is not a safe operation. If you really need this, use try/catch block